# Is there a better way to manage file pointer in C?

Tags: c, file, pointers

Is it better to use `fopen()` and `fclose()` at the beginning and end of every function that use that file, or is it better to pass the file pointer to every of these function ? Or even to set the file pointer as an element of the struct the file is related to.
I have two projects going on and each one use one method (because I thought about passing the file pointer after I began the first one).
When I say better, I mean in term of speed and/or readability. What's best practice ?

Thank you !

Comment: It depends on how you're using the file, and how often you need to read/write, and many other factors.

Comment: This seems to be a rather broad, opinion-based question. In *general*, I'd say that it's better to open the file once, do whatever you need to with it, and then close it once you're done, but without a practical, real-life context for this question I can't really say what's best - there may be situations where a file only needs to be accessed infrequently, in which case an open-as-needed policy might be better.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You certainly should document what function is [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)-ing a `FILE` handle and what function is expecting to [fclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) it.

You might put the `FILE*` in a `struct` but you should have a convention about who and when should the file be read and/or written and closed.

Be aware that opened files are some expansive resources in a process (=your running program). BTW, it is also [operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) specific. And `FILE` handles are buffered, see [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) & [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)

On small systems, the maximal number of `fopen`-ed files handles could be as small as a few dozens. On a current Linux desktop, a process could have a few thousand opened [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (which the internal `FILE` is keeping, with its buffers). In any case, it is a rather precious and scare resource (on Linux, you might limit it with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html))

Be aware that disk IO is very slow w.r.t. CPU.